# Excel, Filters, Filter a column that the text begins with several different letters

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

How do I filter a Column that starts with different letters?

for example,  I need to exclude all the data that starts with the letter a, b , c and d.

I've seen I can use the filter "begins with" but it only let me filter maximum 2 letters at the time. how do I do it to do more than 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using VBA, you can put a helper column next to the column you want to filter. If, for example, the original is col A, you could put the formula below in col B and filter to show only rows with "FALSE."

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)="a",LEFT(A2,1)="b",LEFT(A2,1)="c",LEFT(A2,1)="d"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it. Go ahead and mark it as the correct answer when you get a chance.